# List all users from Github organization && avoid Octokit gem limits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-api, octokit

I'm using [Octokit gem](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) for communication with Github API. Using this gem I want to list all users from my organization and show their login names. Based on a docs it's straight forward:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: ENV.fetch('PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN'))
client.organization_members('my_organization')
```

The thing is there is some kind of limitations because I'm getting only 30 records instead of over 600. How to avoid such limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting only 30 records instead of over 600.

GitHub API defaults to 30 items per page, and won't follow pagination by default. Please check the [pagination docs](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb#pagination) to see how to use it.

It might be as easy as this:

```rb
client.auto_paginate = true
issues = client.issues 'rails/rails'
issues.length

# => 702
```